# ngModel returns empty result to CreateComponent

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ngmodel

I want to capture the `Employee` result, so I defined the `Employee` object and try to capture those values using `[ngModel]`, but I get empty results. could you please help me to resolve this?

Employee.ts

```js
import {IEmployee} from "../_interfaces/IEmployee";
import {ISalary} from "../_interfaces/ISalary";
import {IDesignation} from "../_interfaces/IDesignation";

export class Employee implements IEmployee {
  public birth_date: string;
  public designations: IDesignation;
  public emp_no: string;
  public first_name: string;
  public gender: string;
  public hire_date: string;
  public id: string;
  public last_name: string;
  public salaries: ISalary;

  constructor(
    birth_date: string,
    designations: IDesignation,
    emp_no: string,
    first_name: string,
    gender: string,
    hire_date: string,
    id: string,
    last_name: string,
    salaries: ISalary,
  ) {
    this.birth_date = birth_date;
    this.designations = designations;
    this.emp_no = emp_no;
    this.first_name = first_name;
    this.gender = gender;
    this.hire_date = hire_date;
    this.id = id;
    this.last_name = last_name;
    this.salaries = salaries;
  }


}
```

create.component.ts

```js
export class CreateComponent implements OnInit {


  public employee: Employee= {
    birth_date: "",
    designations: <Designations>{
      id: '',
      title: '',
      emp_no: '',
      from_date: '',
      to_date: '',
    },
    emp_no: "",
    first_name: "",
    gender: "",
    hire_date: "",
    id: "",
    last_name: "",
    salaries: <Salary>{
      id: "",
      emp_no: "",
      salary: "",
      rom_date: "",
      to_date: "",
    },
  };

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  getValues(){
    console.log(this.employee);
  }


}
```

create.component.html

```
<label>First Name</label>
<input [ngModel]="employee.first_name"  [ngModelOptions]="{standalone:true}" class="form-control" type="text">
<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="getValues()">Save Entries</button>
```

Output

> NULL

Answer (score 1):

Use `[(ngModel)]` instead of `[ngModel]` for two-way binding.

[NgModel (Description)](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel#description)

> If you have a one-way binding to ngModel with [] syntax, changing the domain model's value in the component class sets the value in the view. If you have a two-way binding with [()] syntax (also known as 'banana-in-a-box syntax'), the value in the UI always syncs back to the domain model in your class.

```
<input [(ngModel)]="employee.first_name"  [ngModelOptions]="{standalone:true}" class="form-control" type="text">
```

[Sample Demo on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pja8wg?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: Fixed. thanks ! I have small question. Employees has two objects. salaries & designations . So could you please check my `employee` variable ? whether i create it right or wrong format.

Comment: [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-8mvs9v?file=src/app/Employee.ts). There is a conflict between your `Employee` for `designations: IDesignation` and `salaries: ISalary` while in Component you specify `designations: Designation` and `salaries: Salary`.